# Multiple facebook likes buttons

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a problem with multiple facebook likes on webpage. Each item has it's own facebook like button. Everything works fine, but when i look to firebug i see something like this:[image]

Is this possible to eliminate this repeated reqests?
Some code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And then fb_like button:

```
<fb:like href="http://unique_url_here.com" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the init code multiple times accidentally?

You need one `fb-root` div, one include of the all.js, and multiple 
`<fb:likes`

Comment: There is only one fb-root and one include .You can see the issue here  http://domorethanwork.com/

Comment: Loading that page I see exactly _one_ request going to Facebook, and that’s for the all.js. Are you talking about something else here than just loading the page, i.e. actually using some of the like buttons?

Comment: I've just hide all the like buttons, now there are loaded dynamically. Click the share button below some video or image and look into the console. There goes 3 requst. Click antother one and there are 3 more request. At beginning when like buttons ware visible, there comes much more reqests.